# How to change permissions for all the files belonging to selected users

Tags: linux, bash, debian

The script loops for every user found containing the string RECHERCHE (exported from another script) and changes their permissions, and their default permissions. I'm getting a syntax error whenever I try to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do

        if [-z  "$(grep "/home" | cut -d: -f5 | grep -i "$RECHERCHE")" ]
              then
        user=$(cut -f: -f1)
        file=$(find / -user user)
        if [$(stat -c %a file) >= 700]
                then
        chmod 700 file
        fi
        if [$(stat -c %a file) < 600]
            then
        chmod 600 file
        fi
        umask 177
done 2>> /home/$user/challenge.log
```

I know this may seem as a lot of questions at once, but when I try to run it, it gives me a syntax error on the done (line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `done'), so I have no idea if the logic behind it works. Also, I have no idea what I'm doing. Please help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a fi.  And I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the line you read.  I can't obviously run this, you'll need to finish fixing it up, but that particular problem with done is resolved see the following version of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
while $line ; do
        if [-z  "$(grep "/home" | cut -d: -f5 | grep -i "$RECHERCHE")" ]; then
                user=$(cut -f: -f1)
                file=$(find / -user user)
                if [$(stat -c %a file) >= 700]; then
                        chmod 700 file
                fi
                if [$(stat -c %a file) < 600]; then
                        chmod 600 file
                fi
                umask 177
        fi
        read line
done 2>> /home/$user/challenge.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, one if condition closing is missing.